# Checking $(\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z})\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

As the title says, I want to make sure $(\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z})\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}=0$ and to check if my reasoning is correct.

Obviously, $0\otimes 1=(0+0)\otimes 1=0\otimes 1+0\otimes 1$, so $0\otimes 1=0$.

On the other hand, consider a simple tensor $a\otimes x$. Since $ka=0$, it follows that
$$a\otimes x=a\otimes(xk/k)=(ka)\otimes(x/k)=0\otimes(x/k)=(x/k)(0\otimes 1)=0.$$
Thus every simple tensor is zero, and therefore $(\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z})\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}=0$

Comment: Yes, this is a fine proof. It actually works with $\mathbb R$ replaced by any abelian group $A$ such that for $b\in A,$ $\exists a\in A$ such that $ka=b.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensor product with $\mathbf{Q}_p/\mathbf{Z}_p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4297880/tensor-product-with-mathbfq-p-mathbfz-p) The accepted answer gives a very short proof (same as yours) of: "More generally, if $T$ is a torsion abelian group and $D$ is a divisible abelian group, then $T\otimes D=0$."

Comment: In particular, it works for $A=\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z,$ where $\gcd(k,m)=1.$